# How should I initialize interface types from the windows crate?

Tags: winapi, rust, com, windows-rs

I have a struct that uses some types from the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, but I'm not able to initialize them:

```
use windows::Win32::{
    IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler, IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler_Vtbl,
};

// Here's my struct:
pub struct EventHandler {
    // A struct member to handle the event:
    event: IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler,
    event_vtbl: IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler_Vtbl,
}

// Anyone with experience in the windows API
// Will understand the Virtual tables, and this code.

impl EventHandler {
    pub fn new() -> EventHandler {
        // Here, I should return a new instance of my struct:
        EventHandler {
            // Now, I should initialize every struct member:
            event: IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler {}, // ...
            event_vtbl: IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler_Vtbl {
                // This struct needs two members:
                base__: IUnknown {}, // IUnknown requires a lot of
                                     // methods and member initialization to initialize it.
                                     // Also the IUIAutomationFocusChangedEvent needs too member initialization....
            },
        }
    }
}
```

These structs shouldn't be initialized in C++ winapi. I don't know what should I do. Every struct needs member initialization, and every member needs other members, and other members need member initialization!

I feel like I'm in a whirlpool! Am I missing something?

Comment: See [How do I implement an existing COM interface?](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-implement-an-existing-com-interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the literal question first: You could, but you probably shouldn't have to.

COM support in the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate exposes many types, and not all of them are meant for immediate use by client code. The `*_Vtbl` structures specifically represent the raw function pointer tables used by COM internally to dispatch interface calls. They are declared and populated by the library and not intended to be used by clients directly (the `#[doc(hidden)]` attribute is a hint, though I'm sure the library structure and documentation experience can be improved).

Attempting to populate the v-tables in client code puts you into a miserable situation. Luckily, none of that is required, as briefly explained in the [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-implement-an-existing-com-interface):

> #### How do I implement an existing COM interface?
>
> If you need to implement a COM interface for a type, you'll need to add the `implement` feature which (like any Cargo feature) can be enabled in your project's Cargo.toml file.
>
> ```ini
> windows = { version = "..", features = ["implement"] }
> ```
>
> Then you'll need to declare that your type implements a particular interface by adding the `#[implement]` proc macro to your type and then writing an `impl` block for the interface. For an interface called `IMyInterface` you will need to implement the `IMyInterface_Impl` trait (note the trailing `_Impl` in the name).
>
> ```rust
> #[windows::core::implement(IMyInterface)]
> struct MyStruct;
>
> impl IMyInterface_Impl for MyStruct {
>    fn MyMethod(&self) -> windows::core::HRESULT {
>        todo!("Your implementation goes here");
>    }
> }
> ```

Version [0.37.0](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/releases/tag/0.37.0) made significant changes to the `implement` macro, making this far more approachable than it may appear. Let's start out by declaring a simple structure with a bit of state information:

```rust
#[implement(IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler)]
struct EventHandler {
    count: Cell<u64>,
}

impl EventHandler {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            count: Cell::new(0),
        }
    }

    /// Increments the count and returns the new value
    fn increment(&self) -> u64 {
        let new_val = self.count.get() + 1;
        self.count.set(new_val);
        new_val
    }
}
```

This keeps a cumulative count of focus change events that happened. Note that the implementation isn't actually correct: Since the event handler can be called from multiple threads we'd actually need a type that's `Sync` (which `Cell` isn't). That's something you'd need to change<sup>1</sup>.

What's missing is the [`IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationfocuschangedeventhandler) interface implementation. It only has a single member, so that's easy (the `IUnknown` implementation is conveniently provided for you by the library already):

```rust
impl IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler_Impl for EventHandler {
    fn HandleFocusChangedEvent(&self, _sender: &Option<IUIAutomationElement>) -> Result<()> {
        let count = self.increment();
        println!("Focus changed (cumulative count: {})", count);

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

For every focus change event it first increments the cumulative count and then prints a message to STDOUT.

That's all that's required to implement a custom `IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler` interface. Using that from a program isn't much harder, either, even though there are a lot of pitfalls (see comments):

```rust
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Initialize COM for the current thread. Since we are running event handlers on this
    // thread, it needs to live in the MTA.
    // See [Understanding Threading Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-threading)
    // for more information.
    unsafe { CoInitializeEx(ptr::null(), COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) }?;

    // Instantiate a `CUIAutomation` object
    let uia: IUIAutomation =
        unsafe { CoCreateInstance(&CUIAutomation, None, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER) }?;

    // Subscribe to the focus changed event; this transfers ownership of `handler` into
    // `uia`, making it the sole owner
    let handler = EventHandler::new();
    unsafe { uia.AddFocusChangedEventHandler(None, &handler.into()) }?;

    // Display a message box so that we have an easy way to quit the program
    let _ = unsafe {
        MessageBoxW(
            None,
            w!("Click OK to end the program"),
            w!("UIA Focus Monitor"),
            MB_OK,
        )
    };

    // Optionally unsubscribe from all events; this is not strictly required since we have
    // to assume that the `CUIAutomation` object properly manages the lifetime of our
    // `EventHandler` object
    unsafe { uia.RemoveAllEventHandlers() }?;

    // IMPORTANT: Do NOT call `CoUninitialize()` here. `uia`'s `Drop` implementation will
    // get very angry at us when it runs after COM has been uninitialized

    Ok(())
}
```

To compile the code you'll want to use the following imports:

```rust
use std::{cell::Cell, ptr};
use windows::{
    core::{implement, Result},
    w,
    Win32::{
        System::Com::{
            CoCreateInstance, CoInitializeEx, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED,
        },
        UI::{
            Accessibility::{
                CUIAutomation, IUIAutomation, IUIAutomationElement,
                IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler, IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler_Impl,
            },
            WindowsAndMessaging::{MessageBoxW, MB_OK},
        },
    },
};
```

and this *Cargo.toml* file:

```ini
[package]
name = "uia_focus_change"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.39.0"
features = [
    "implement",
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_UI_Accessibility",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Possible alternatives include an [`AtomicU64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU64.html) and a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). An atomic is perfectly sufficient here, is easy to use, and will properly work in situations of re-entrancy:*

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU64, Ordering};
#[implement(IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler)]
struct EventHandler {
    count: AtomicU64,
}

impl EventHandler {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            count: AtomicU64::new(0),
        }
    }

    /// Increments the count and returns the new value
    fn increment(&self) -> u64 {
        self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst) + 1
    }
}
```

*A mutex, on the other hand, is substantially harder to use, its behavior in part unspecified, and equipped with lots of opportunities to fail. On the upside it is more versatile in protecting arbitrarily large structures:*

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
#[implement(IUIAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler)]
struct EventHandler {
    count: Mutex<u64>,
}

impl EventHandler {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            count: Mutex::new(0),
        }
    }

    /// Increments the count and returns the new value
    fn increment(&self) -> u64 {
        let mut guard = self.count.lock().expect("Failed to lock mutex");
        *guard += 1;
        *guard
    }
}
```

*Either one works and is compatible with COM objects that live in the [MTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/multithreaded-apartments).*